# Strange number using hep-math package

Tags: packages, bugs

I wanted reproduce this image, using [hep-math](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hep-math/hep-math-implementation.pdf) package

[image]

at the link [Diffcoeff turns ordinary derivative into partial derivative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521556/diffcoeff-turns-ordinary-derivative-into-partial-derivative)

but when I put in the `x` a superscript `\sigma` to the denominator I see a strange number:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hep-math}
\renewcommand{\diffsymbol}{\mathrm d}
\begin{document}
\[
\pdv[]x^{\sigma} \dv[f]x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why? Is it a bug?

Comment: "I see a strange number". You have me rolling around laughing so hard right now! You totally made my day!! Keep up the great work!!!

Comment: Oh, and do check what happens if you replace `x^{\sigma}` with `{x^{\sigma}}`.

Comment: @Mico I'm so glad it made you laugh. This strange number popped up for me and I wondered why. Anyway your solution in the comment solves the problem +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is expecting a numeric exponent.  If you use `x^{n}` you get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   n
```

with `\sigma` that is defined by:

```
> \sigma=\mathchar"11B.
l.4 \show\sigma
```

so if used in a numeric context it works as hex 11B which is decimal 283 and produces the output you show.

If you want to use the macro you can treat `x^\sigma` as the variable rather than `\sigma` as the order of the partial derivative so

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hep-math}
\renewcommand{\diffsymbol}{\mathrm d}
\begin{document}
\[
\pdv[]{x^{\sigma}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: David thank you very much. The solution is the double `{}`.